# problem faced while setting value using reflection

Tags: java

i am using reflection to copy values of fields from object of Class A to object of Class B.
However method in A returns Number, where as setter in B requires Long. Is there any generic way i could set the value. As of now as expected i get illegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

```
class a
{
    Number value1;
    Number value2;
    public Number getValue1(){return value1;}
    public Number getValue2(){return value2;}

}

class b
{
    Double value1;
    Long   value2;
    public void setValue1(Double value){this.value1 = value;}
    public void setValue2(Long value){this.value2 = value;}

}
```

Not sure if my question is unclear.

Comment: It would be good if your code corresponded to your question.  You don't have any getters or setters here.

Comment: BTW: I suggest you use primitives like double and long, unless you know you need an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
b.setValue2(a.getValue2().longValue());
```

But if `a.value2` isn't actually an integer (e.g. it's a `Double` with a fractional component) this will lose data.

Correspondingly

```
b.setValue1(a.getValue1().doubleValue());
```

### Edit

Ok I think I've got a grasp on your situation.  Here's a dirty way to go about what you want to do.  Basically you need to have a transform method which will transform a Number into another Number based on a chosen class.  That class you get from the `Method` itself.  So it will be something like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      A a = new A();
      a.setValue1(1.0);
      a.setValue2(5);

      B b = new B();

      Method[] methods = b.getClass().getMethods();
      for ( Method m : methods ) {
         if ( m.getName().equals("setValue2") ) {
            m.invoke(b, transform(a.getValue2(), m.getParameterTypes()[0]));
         }
      }
      System.out.println(b.getValue2());
   }

   private static Number transform(Number n, Class<?> toClass) {
      if ( toClass == Long.class ) {
         return n.longValue();
      } else if ( toClass == Double.class ) {
         return n.doubleValue();
      }
      //instead of this you should handle the other cases exhaustively
      return null;
   }
```

The reason you would otherwise get an `IllegalArgumentException` in the above is because with `a`, `value2` is not being set to a `Long`, it's being set to an `Integer`.  They are disjoint types.  If `a.value2` was actually set to be a Long instead, you wouldn't have that error.

Comment: @icon666: How are you invoking that setter such that you don't know what setter you're invoking?

Comment: @icon666 so do you have multiple setters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the conversion:

```
// get the Number 'number'
Long l = new Long(number.longValue());
// store the Long
```

You could do it even more efficiently using autoboxing.

Comment: Autoboxing or not, you should at least be using `Long.valueOf(...)`.

Comment: And check its not a Long already which can be simply cast (Long).

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I think runtime type identification via `instanceof` and having an `if-else` would be more expensive that calling always the "virtual" method `longValue`.

Comment: Hmm, this is basically what I already said, which the OP already said doesn't work for him/her.

Comment: @fortran: I don't think it's calling the method that's expensive, it's potentially creating an unnecessary object.  Depends on the range of values and the size of the Long cache.

Comment: @Mark The asker said COPY the value so I assumed they always wanted to duplicate the object rather than create a reference to the existing one.

Comment: @DJClayworth:  Why in God's name would anybody want to create a duplicate instance of a Long (or really any immutable object for that matter)?  If you really thought that's what the asker wanted (personally I thought it was pretty clear they just wanted the fields in `b` to have the same value as the fields in `a`), you should've corrected him/her.

Comment: @fortran, the instanceof is cheap but creating a Long to wrap a value which was already a Long is relatively expensive.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey you're right, I was overlooking that `longValue` returns a basic type and thus it will be boxed into a new `Long` rather than returning a reference to the same object (as happens with `String.toString`).

Comment: @fortran, if your long values are between -128 and 127, it won't matter as these values are cached.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yeah, I had already taken a peek at the implementation to check that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a 'generic' way, because a `Number` could be a `Float`, `Byte` etc.